# Codeblocks Ubuntu 14.04 brackets auto-indent not working

Tags: codeblocks, ubuntu-14.04

I have installed Codeblocks 13.12 on Ubuntu 14.04 and am facing a problem while inserting curly braces in the source program. 
When I insert '{', this happens:

```
{|}
```

i.e. my cursor is inside the pair and I have to press [ENTER] each time to indent the braces. This wasn't a problem in windows versions. It should be like this:

```
{
   |
}
```

How to enable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the SmartIndent* plugins installed and enabled?

If not, that would be your problem I beleive.

Comment: Yes, they were enabled. Turns out the solution to this is to install an additional package.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/438747/auto-indentation-not-working-in-code-blocks-13-12-svn-9636

Problem Solved.

Comment: Glad you got it fixed. I thought it had to do with a package.

Comment: Yeah indeed that could've been the reason. But I had taken care of that previously. :)